# C# .NET API multiple save.changes() transactions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api, transactions

I wanted to confirm If this is the best way to handle EF6 transactions in .NET API. So if the API changes only a single Entity for example update potato count in user owned potatos. I do not need to enclose it with

```
using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) {}
```

because the EF will not commit the changes if it can't. But if the single API endpoint updates multiple Entities for expl. API endpoint createSoup() which removes multiple vegitables from user and creates a new entity soup for a usse. Then I do need enclose it with the mentioned statement in case it removes the vegitables, but was unable to create the soup entity and vice versa. Is there no other way? because it seems a little overkill to put all the api endpoint function (which edit mulptile entities) inside this statement.

Comment: How many `context.SaveChanges();` do you have? If you have a single call, the you don't need to do anything.

Comment: There are some operations where there are two of them since the following operation required and entity Id which is not generated until the SaveChanges() is callled :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the operations on your app where to apply `Database.BeginTransaction()` method.

The functionality of the `Database.BeginTransaction()` method is,
you can `start` and `complete` transactions themselves within an existing `DbContext`.In other words it allows several operations to be combined within the same transaction and hence either `all committed` or `all rolled back` as one.And It also allows you to specify the `isolation level` for the transaction.

So if you don't need that functionality,then you can easily use `context.SaveChanges()` only.As I mentioned earlier you have to clearly identity the operations where you need to apply `Transactions`.

**Note :** If you need to handle transactions,then you must use `Database.BeginTransaction()` method.There is no other way.

***Reference :*** [**Working with Transactions (EF6 Onwards)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx)

Comment: Regarding your final note: Another option is to use a `TransactionScope`.

Comment: That is `Prior to EF6`.It's having lot of limitations.If you're using `new Database.BeginTransaction()` API then `TransactionScope` approach is no longer necessary for most users @Maarten

Comment: You're warmly welcome :) please see the reference which I have mentioned above @MattJ

Comment: @Sampath I know it is a different solution, and yes, it has limitations, but it is an option. Maybe there is no context yet at the point in the code where the two (or multiple) db-context-actions are triggered.

Comment: Yes,we can do that.But we must always try to promote to use `Latest and Smartest` `APIs`.such APIs will remove huge headaches which we had early days :) @Maarten